# Excel 2013 OLAP Tools DAX Tabular Data Connection

Tags: sql, excel, ssas, mdx, tabular

I have an `Excel 2013` pivot table on a tabular model data connection. I essentially want to slice the facttable.sales field by a calculated field on a product dimension that doesn't exist in the model. Using my `TSQL` background to explain the field I want, the only way I know how:

```
Case when productdimension.category = A then 'sourcesystem1'
else 'sourcesystem2'
```

Can you write `DAX` in the "`MDX Calculated Member`" option in excel's `OLAP tools` for tabular models ? Would I use this feature for what I want to do ?

Depending if you can write `DAX` or need to write `MDX` for this, is what I described possible / how would I write that?

I assume this should be done upstream on the `ETL /model` side of things but this is for a 1 off report. Additionally, I would like to know if this is possible generally speaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a calculated member for this in Excel. This is probably fine, as long as it really is a one-off report. If you find that other people start using this same field, you should really at least add it as a calculated column in the tabular model, if not add it into the ETL earlier in the process.

That said, you can write MDX for a calculated a measure in Excel.  This works for Excel 2013 and 2016. I don't have older versions to test.
As you suggested, go to OLAP Tools -> MDX Calculated Measure. The MDX for the calculated measure would be would be

```
Case [ProductionDimension].[Category].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION 
WHEN 'A' THEN 'sourcesystem1' Else 'sourcesystem2' END
```

Comment: `mdx` tag has been proposed for documentation - can you add your vote please as we need several votes to create the documentation for this tag: stackoverflow.com/documentation/mdx